# How to use Android Storage Access Framework in flutter(SAF)

Tags: flutter, saf

I'm trying to use [SAF](https://pub.dev/packages/saf) in flutter. everything is fine. But one specific problem is I' have to request access to folder every time I want to read from the folder. Even if user has already granted access to folder.

I have tried different options specified in the official documentation but I can not get it right